# .xinitrc and .xsession not running

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to get some commands to run in these files nothing is working.

First file `~/.xinitrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo DERP >>  /home/karl/xinitrc-derp1.log
```

Second file `~/.xsession`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo DERP >>  /home/karl/xsession-derp1.log
```

The logs just do not appear. I'm running pantheon with Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`~/.xsessionrc` was the file to use.